# How can I use vue validation with Jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vee-validate

I'm writing a unit test with vue 3 using vee-validate 4 and Jest. But I'm new to this and I'm stuck at one place.
I have a TextInput component that I use validations, and when I call this component, I do validation when submit is done.
There is a separate component where I write the form where I use these textInputs.
First let me show you the code in my TkTextInput component.

```
<template>
  <div
      class="tk-Input"
      :class="{ 'has-error': !!errorMessage, success: meta.valid }"
  >
    <label class="tk-label" :for="name">{{ label }}</label>
    <input
        id="demos"
        class="col-12"
        v-model="inputValue"
        :name="name"
        :type="type"
        :value="inputValue"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        @input="handleChange"
        @blur="handleBlur"
        v-bind="$attrs"
    />

    <p class="help-message" v-show="errorMessage || meta.valid">
      {{ errorMessage }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {useField} from "vee-validate";
import {watch} from "vue";

export default {
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "text",
    },
    modelValue: String,
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  setup(props, {emit}) {

    const {
      value: inputValue,
      errorMessage,
      handleBlur,
      handleChange,
      meta,
    } = useField(props.name, undefined, {
      initialValue: props.value,
    });

    watch(inputValue, (val) => {
      emit('update:modelValue', val);
    });

    watch(() => props.modelValue, (val) => {
      if (val !== inputValue.value) {
        inputValue.value = val;
      }
    })
    return {
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      errorMessage,
      meta,
      inputValue,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Then in my form component where I call these textInputs is as follows.

```
<Form
    @submit="onSubmit"
    :validation-schema="schema">
  <div class="grid ">
  <div class="col-12  lg:col-6 lg:mb-0">
    <tk-text-input v-model.trim="vehicleInfo.Plate" label="Plaka*" name="Plate" type="text"/>
  </div>
 
  <div class="grid ">
    <div class="col-12  lg:col-6 lg:mb-0">
      <tk-text-input v-model.trim="vehicleInfo.PhoneNumber" label="Cep Telefonu*" name="PhoneNumber"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 lg:col-6 lg:mb-0">
    </div>
  </div>
  <Button @click="clicked" class=" p-button-success" type="submit">{{buttonLabel}}</Button>
</Form>
```

Now I want to test the validation process in the TkTextInput component when the button clicks when I click the button in the component where I wrote the form with gesture. But I couldn't do it.

The test I wrote in the .spec file is as follows.

```
describe('TkTextInput.vue', () => {
  it('when validation is done',   async() => {
    const wrapperVehicle = mount(VehicleInfoDialog, {
      global:{
        plugins: [PrimeVue]
      },
    })
     const button = wrapperVehicle.find("button")
    button.trigger('submit')
    await button.trigger("click")
      expect(wrapperVehicle.html()).toContain("Boş Geçilemez.")

    });
  })
```